# PHP code from random images not working, images broken

Tags: php, html, image, random

I'm trying to insert 5 images randomly chosen from a folder in an html file and I have this php code however the images remain broken

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
$dir = ‘images/’;
$images = scandir($dir);
$i = rand(2, sizeof($images)-1);
?>
```

and the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page Title Goes Here</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php include("random-image.php") ?>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $images[$i]; ?>" alt=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

I have very little experience with php so I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Do you create the array `$images` in your PhP file ? cause I don't see this array here... what does the resulting HTML look like ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "broken"?

Comment: I mean the links are broken so images arent there

Comment: First thing, your curly quotes will stop your code **dead in its tracks**. Change `‘images/’` to `'images/'`

Comment: @fred ok fixed but the code still isn't working

Comment: @user2994128: Add `var_dump($images[$i]);` in your PHP code and access the script *directly8. What does it output?

Comment: @amal ok i added it, what do you mean access it directly?

Comment: @user2994128: Run the script. Load the webpage directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this,

```
$dir = 'images/';
$images = glob($dir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
```

Comment: So use this as the php code file instead, do I sill leave the img src code the same?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same by replacing `$i`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following to see if you are getting into the directory at all.

```
$baseDirectory = "/images";

$imgDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $baseDirectory;

$images = scandir($imgDirectory);

if (count($images)) {
    unset($images['.']);
    unset($images['..']);

    $i = rand(1, count($images)) - 1;
}else{
    echo "There are no images.";
}
```

Comment: True but `sizeof` is confusing for most readers period.  It should still be changed to `count`.

Comment: @user2994128 What happened when you did the `print_r($images);`?  Or do you mean even with that there was no change?

Comment: even with that added to the php code, there was no change in what was shown in the html page when testing it in a browser

Comment: It sounds like you are not getting the directory information at all then.  I will update my answer shortly for better checking.